# django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned error in Django-Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, python-social-auth

I'm encountering an issue when trying to access the 'kakao' provider in Django-allauth. (Actually, google has a version issue now so, I want to figure it out kakao first) I have an exception for MultipleObjectsReturned or ObjectDoesNotExist. I have followed the documentation and tried various troubleshooting steps, but the problem persists.

Here is the code from my views.py file:

```
def kakao_callback(request):
    code = request.GET.get("code")
    print(f"code : {code}")
    
    # ---- Access Token Request ----
    token_req = requests.get(
        f"https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={KAKAO_REST_API_KEY}&redirect_uri={KAKAO_REDIRECT_URI}&code={code}"
    )
    token_req_json = token_req.json()
    error = token_req_json.get("error", None)
    if error is not None:
        raise JSONDecodeError(f"Failed to decode JSON: {error}", '{"error": "your_error_message"}', 0)

    access_token = token_req_json.get("access_token")
    print(f"access_token : {access_token}")
    
    # ---- Email Request ----
    profile_request = requests.post(
        "https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/user/me",
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"},
    )
    profile_json = profile_request.json()
    error = profile_json.get("error", None)
    if error is not None:
        raise JSONDecodeError("Failed to decode JSON", '{"error": "your_error_message"}', 0)

    kakao_account = profile_json.get("kakao_account")
    email = kakao_account.get("email", None)
    profile = kakao_account.get("profile")
    nickname = profile.get("nickname")
    profile_image = profile.get("thumbnail_image_url")
    # print(email)
    
    # ---- Signup or Signin Request ----
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        social_user = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=user)
        if social_user is None:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"err_msg": "email exists but not kakao social user"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
        if social_user.provider != "kakao":
            return JsonResponse(
                {"err_msg": "no matching social type"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
            

        data = {"access_token": access_token, "code": code}
        accept = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}accounts/kakao/login/finish/", data=data)
        accept_status = accept.status_code
        
        if accept_status != 200:
            print(f"Accept request status code: {accept.status_code}")
            return JsonResponse({"err_msg": "failed to signin_registered user."}, status=accept_status)
        accept_json = accept.json()
        accept_json.pop('user', None)
        refresh_token = accept.headers['Set-Cookie']
        refresh_token = refresh_token.replace('=',';').replace(',',';').split(';')
        token_index = refresh_token.index(' refresh_token')
        cookie_max_age = 3600 * 24 * 14 # 14 days
        refresh_token = refresh_token[token_index+1]
        response_cookie = JsonResponse(accept_json)
        response_cookie.set_cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, max_age=cookie_max_age, httponly=True, samesite='Lax')
        return response_cookie
    
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        cookie_max_age = 3600 * 24 * 14
        data = {"access_token": access_token, "code": code}
        accept = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}accounts/kakao/login/finish/", data=data)
        accept_status = accept.status_code  
    
        if accept_status != 200:
            print(f"Failed to signup_new user. Status code: {accept_status}")
            return JsonResponse({"err_msg": "failed to signup_new user"}, status=accept_status)

        accept_json = accept.json()
        accept_json.pop('user', None)
        refresh_token = accept.headers['Set-Cookie']
        refresh_token = refresh_token.replace('=',';').replace(',',';').split(';')
        token_index = refresh_token.index(' refresh_token')
        refresh_token = refresh_token[token_index+1]

        response_cookie = JsonResponse(accept_json)
        response_cookie.set_cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, max_age=cookie_max_age, httponly=True, samesite='Lax')
        return response_cookie
    
    except JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"JSONDecodeError: {e}")
        raise
    
    except User.MultipleObjectsReturned as e:
        print(f"MultipleObjectsReturned: {e}")
        return JsonResponse(
            {"err_msg": "MultipleObjectsReturned. Check logs for details."},
            status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        )
    
    except:
        return JsonResponse({"MESSAGE":"KEY_ERROR"}, status=400)
```

I have checked the database, and there are two entries for the 'kakao', and 'google' providers in the SocialApp table. The client_id is correctly set for this provider. Also, when I checked the `SocialApp.objects.all()` it came out <QuerySet `[<SocialApp: Kakao>, <SocialApp: google>]`>.

Here is the code of SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS from settings.py file:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'kakao': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': KAKAO_SECRET_KEY,
            'secret': KAKAO_REST_API_KEY,
        }
    },
    'google': {
        'APP':{
            'clinet_id':secrets['SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'],
            'secret': secrets['SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET']
            },
    }
}
```

Tracelog:

```
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\Pj\Lib\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\adapter.py", line 290, in get_app
    raise MultipleObjectsReturned
django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are setting up social applications in both the database and the settings because of this conflict.

From the allauth documentation:

> Important: While you can mix both methods, be aware you need to avoid
> configuring one and the same provider both via settings.py and a
> SocialApp instance. In that case, it is not clear what app to pick,
> resulting in a MultipleObjectsReturned exception.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).